# Prevent child elements from being the target when parent element is clicked

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

```
toggleMenu(element) {
    const el = element.target
    if(hasClass(el, this.activeClass)){
        el.classList.remove(this.activeClass)
    } else {
        el.classList.add(this.activeClass)
    }
}



 <div onClick={ this.toggleMenu.bind(this) } style={this.style} className ="vis-menu-toggle">
     <div className="box" style={styles.box}>
         <div className="top" style={styles.topLine}/>
         <div className="middle" style={styles.middleLine}/>
         <div className="top" style={styles.bottomLine}/>
      </div>
  </div>
```

I want to add a class to the parent div when clicked, but if it clicks the inner div the targeted element is not the parent and the child recieves the class.. How do I prevent this?

Comment: Side note: `element` is a slightly odd name for a parameter that will receive an event object, not an element. :-)

Answer (score 5):

Use [`currentTarget`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget) instead of `target`. It's the element the event is currently being dispatched to.

Example:

```js
class Example extends React.Component {
  constructor(...args) {
    super(...args);
    this.activeClass = "active";
  }

  toggleMenu(element) {
      const el = element.currentTarget;
      el.classList.toggle(this.activeClass);
  }
  
  render() {
    return <div onClick={ this.toggleMenu.bind(this) } className="vis-menu-toggle">
       Topmost div
       <div className="box">
        Box
        <div className="top">top 1</div>
        <div className="middle">middle</div>
        <div className="top">top 2</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Example />,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```css
.active {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

---

Side note:

- `classList` has `toggle`, no need for the `if/else` (and you'd forgotten the `el.classList` in front of it)